# Ring Properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $(S,.,+)$ is a ring with the property that $a^2 = a$ for all a an element of $S$, which of the following must be true, given:

**I** $a + a = 0$ for all $a\in{  S}$.

**II** $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 $ for all $a, b \in{ S}.$

**III** S is commutative.

- A. III only
- B. I and II only
- C. I and III only
- D. II, and III only
- E. I, II, and III

Help please I know that it is not only III so A. is out.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+ba+b^2=a+ab+ba+b=a+b$$
hence we find
$$ab=-ba$$
and 
$$(ab)^2=abab=a(-ab)b=-a^2b^2=-ab=ab=-ba$$
hence
$$ab=ba=-ba$$
finally we have
$$(a+a)^2=a^2+a^2+a^2+a^2=a+a+a+a=a+a$$
so 
$$a+a=0$$
and then the three assertions are true.

Answer (score 1):

- I: Let $a ∈ S$. Then $a = a^2 = (-a)^2 = (-a) = -a$, so $a + a = 0$.
- II: Let $a, b ∈ S$. Then $(a+b)^2 = (a+b) = a + b = a^2 + b^2$.
- III: Let $a, b ∈ S$. Then $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2 = (a^2 + b^2) + (ab + ba)$. By II, subtracting $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$ on both sides yields $ab = -ba$. By I, $ab = ba$.